# Python Object should pretend to be None or empty

Tags: python, object, magic-methods

I have a python class that has certain values. This class is just a wrapper class that is used as a datacontainer inside another class object.

When I have any variable in python, I can check if it is empty (or for that matter equal to False) by simply doing

```
my_variable = "something" 
if my_variable
>>> True

my_variable = None # or False, or 0 or whatever equals False
if my_variable
>>> False
```

So far this is all as usual. But I'd like to behave my class exactly the same but only if a certain attribute has a certain value, otherwise it should return True. Is this possible or does python only check if `my_variable` is bound to something or not?

```
class Test(object):
    def __init__(self, isTrue):
        self.isTrue = isTrue

A = Test(True)
B = Test(False)

if A
>>> True

if B
>>> False
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you are looking for [`__bool__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__bool__) (or [`__nonzero__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__nonzero__) for Python 2).

```
class Test(object):
    def __init__(self, isTrue):
        self.isTrue = isTrue
    def __bool__(self):
        return self.isTrue
```

Comment: ```__nonzero__``` was the clue, Thank you! :)